# C++ / Boost shared resource class for managing resource lifecycle like shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

Does Boost, or anything else, contain a container will act like a shared pointer but allow me to control what happens to the shared 'resource' at the end of it's life? I want to encapsulate an object that can be handed around but, when no longer needed can be closed in a context defined way.

For example, I might want to create and pass around a file handle knowing that when it goes out of scope, the file will be closed automatically, but I don't want to delete the handle.

I could implement it myself, but would rather not get into that if the framework already exists - someone has no doubt done it better. I can't use `boost::shared_ptr`, at least not in it's normal form, as the resource should not be deleted at end of life.

Comment: What version of Boost are you using, that you say doesn't have the `template<class Y, class D> shared_ptr(Y * p, D d);` constructor?

Comment: @SteveJessop: I didn't. I'm afraid the client I'm working for does not allow Boost.

Comment: The TR1 version of `shared_ptr` has it too. Basically the reason you initially stated for not being able to use `boost::shared_ptr` isn't true. This new reason, that the client doesn't allow it, is a lot more compelling. If the client doesn't allow you to use any form of `shared_ptr` (no TR1, no Boost, no C++11), then the answer to your question is "yes, there is a smart pointer that does exactly what you want, but you're not allowed to use it".

Comment: @SteveJessop: Sorry, in light of my original question, I'd probably better qualify this. (1) I'm interested in Boost because it's the most likely framework to have such a container but (2) I can't use Boost because my Client won't allow it, but that doesn't stop me from looking at how this is done in Boost or wherever to better understand it and (3) I could't use a straight shared pointer because it deletes the pointer on going out of scope which isn't what I want *but* I acknowledge it may be possible using a second parameter (below.) Hope that explains things a bit better.

Comment: OK, I think my point then is just that specifying a deleter is still a "straight shared pointer", it's just constructed with a different constructor. Sorry if that's a trivial point to make. It's quite a clever constructor, though: `shared_ptr` does type erasure on the deleter, meaning that the type of the deleter is *not* a template parameter of the `shared_ptr`, only of the constructor. So you can pass a `shared_ptr` around and it's the same type no matter how it is deleted. Reproducing all that yourself is serious PITA.

Comment: @Component10: sorry if I've misunderstood, but is C++0x TR1 or C++11 an option? You've only explicitly ruled out boost...

Comment: @SteveJessop: Agreed on all points.

Comment: @Rook: C++11 is definitely out. TR1 might be an option but, to be honest the client has their own Boost like framework which, generally speaking, tends to implement some very similar facilities to Boost (*please* don't ask why.) However, as I'm not tied to them, my approach in these kinds off situations is to ask how people out in the *real world* are doing this and then check if their own framework implements something similar. If it does, then fine (and in this case it does) and if not, I can moan at them to implement it.

Comment: @Component10: Fair enough. Personally, I wouldn't expect many people in the real world to be trying to reimplement something like `shared_ptr` because it is very complex underneath. Grabbing a working implementation of that would be significantly easier than trying to emulate all its functionality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you aware that `std::shared_ptr` can take a custom deleter class? This need not actually use "delete" or "free", but could easily use some other sort of mechanism (such as a reference counting mechanism's `release` and so on).

Here's a dead simple example for you:

```
std::shared_ptr<FILE> foo(fopen("la", "r"), fclose);
```

The deleter just needs to be a function that takes the pointer type that the `shared_ptr` wraps. In this case, whenfoo goes out of scope, `shared_ptr` will close the file for you. (Note: this isn't a totally sensible implementation, because no error values are checked. It is just an example).

Comment: And as others have noted, the Boost implementation of `shared_ptr` should do the job just fine, too.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a compiler that supports the C++11 `std::shared_ptr`, one of the constructors takes a custom "deleter" function. This would allow you to write your own function for "releasing" the resources.

EDIT -
I forgot that std::shared_ptr was actually in the TR1 update to C++, so if your compiler supports TR1 you should be in good shape.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use Boost or the std::shared_ptr, you could write a smart pointer be it shared or unique that has custom Deleter.